# Passing list to find list of items

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following List item in order to display clearly. I could visualize the small list follows, that could be hundreds rows.

```
CourseId    ClassName    StartDate     EndDate
--------    --------      --------  
12321       Math         08-25-2017     null
14321       Math         08-25-2017     01-05-2018
32342       Physics      08-25-2017     null
34345       Chemistry    08-25-2017     null
25325       Math         01-25-2018     null
45329       Math         01-25-2018     null
33325       Math         01-25-2018     null    
44345       Chemistry    01-25-2018     null
```

I have a list of `CourseId` to find the corresponding items.But the following implementation does not return anything

```
public List<Courses> FindCourses(List<Guid> courseIds, DateTime date, List<Courses>allCourses)
{
  return allCourses.Where(x => CourseId.ToString() == courseIds.ToString() && x.StartDate<= date && x.End_Date.HasValue ? x.End_Date.Value >= date : true).ToList();

}
```

`CourseId` is stored as `GUID`.

Comment: You have your courseIds list as a list of Guid's but the CourseId in the list is not a Guid. Is that correct?

Comment: courseIds.ToString() is a list of guids, your ids in the table are ints

Comment: also your call to string on the list which will probably just return the name of the type, you probably would want to use a contains there instead

Comment: `courseIds.ToString()` probably is the problem. This `ToString()` returns the fully qualified type name, regardless of what is contained in the list.

Comment: CourseId is stored as GUID, since it would be hard to copy and paste long GUID, I just mimicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is more what you're looking for, using `Contains` to check whether the course's ID is in a given list.

```
public List<Courses> FindCourses(List<string> courseIds, DateTime date, List<Courses>allCourses)
{
  return allCourses.Where(x => courseIds.Contains(x.CourseId) && x.StartDate<= date && x.End_Date.HasValue ? x.End_Date.Value >= date : true).ToList();
}
```

(I changed your course IDs to strings, but if they're `int`s or `Guid`s or whatever you can change them to whatever `Course.CourseId`'s type is.)

You can also simplify your EndDate check a little:

```
public List<Courses> FindCourses(List<string> courseIds, DateTime date, List<Courses>allCourses)
{
  return allCourses.Where(x => courseIds.Contains(x.CourseId) 
          && x.StartDate<= date 
          && x.End_Date.HasValue || x.End_Date.Value >= date)
      .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the example you've provided, you are using the wrong Type.  Also you probably want to check if the list contains the id and not call ToString on the list which will just return the name of the type,  You most likely want something closer to this (Assuming Ids is an int and not a string)

```
public List<Courses> FindCourses(List<int> courseIds, DateTime date, 
                                 List<Courses>allCourses)
{
    return allCourses.Where(x => courseIds.Contains(CourseId) 
                             && x.StartDate<= date 
                             && x.End_Date.HasValue 
                                    ? x.End_Date.Value >= date : true)
                     .ToList();

}
```